# Issue retrieving JSON response for ASP.NET Core REST API

Tags: c#, json, azure-sql-database, asp.net-core-3.1

I have referenced the below link and tried to create a POC app:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-blog/10k-request-per-second-rest-api-with-azure-sql-dapper-and-json/ba-p/1189675

```
    [HttpGet("{a}/{b}", Name = "TestMethod")]
    [ProducesResponseType(201)]
    [ProducesResponseType(400)]
    [ProducesResponseType(500)]
    public async Task<JsonElement> TestMethodAsync(long a, long b)
    {
        return await _repo.GetDataAsync(a);
    }

public async Task<JsonElement> GetDataAsync(long a)
{
    JsonDocument result = null;
    const string sql = @"SELECT HC.LeadReviewerEmailAddress, HCRT.ReviewerEmailAddress,
                                ER.PartnerEmailAddress, ER.GroupAuditPartnerEmailAddress, ETM.EmailAddress
                         FROM [EM].[HealthCheck] HC
                         JOIN [EM].[EngagementReview] ER ON ER.EngagementReviewId = HC.EngagementReviewId
                         LEFT JOIN [EM].[HealthCheckReviewTeam] HCRT ON HC.HealthCheckId = HCRT.HealthCheckId
                         LEFT JOIN  [EM].[EngagementTeamMember] ETM ON ETM.EngagementReviewId = HC.EngagementReviewId
                         WHERE HC.HealthCheckId=@a FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER";
    var param = new{a}; 

    using (var conn = await _dapperService.CreateConnection())
    {
        var queryResponse = await conn.QueryAsync<string>(sql, param);
        var allTeamMembersForHC = queryResponse.FirstOrDefault();

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(allTeamMembersForHC))
        {
            result = JsonDocument.Parse(allTeamMembersForHC);
        }
    }

    if (result == null)
        result = JsonDocument.Parse("[]");
        
    return result.RootElement;
}
```

On validating the above method I am getting the below response instead of the JSON string:

```
{
  "valueKind": 2
}
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: I don't see how this question is related to Azure SQL or Dapper. The fact that you are using those technologies should not be relevant to your problem. Can you create a minimal sample that still reproduces your problem? Also, what did you expect the result to be?

Comment: Thanks @julealgon for your response. My expected response is json string, since I am using FOR JSON PATH in the SQL query directly.

Comment: If you expect a `string`, why is your method returning `Task<JsonElement>`?

Answer (score 0):

when using FOR JSON the resultset has only one column and one row, so you have to use the method `ExecuteScalarAsync` instead of `QueryAsync`